# Multiple push notifications on android with wrong icon size

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

Let me preface this post with the fact that I am new to the android programming.

When I issue a notification, the phone shows two notifications for the same thing.  The only difference is, the icons look different and they do different things.  The first will do nothing when you select it.  The other opens the app to the correct page.

I used to only get one notification until I edited this method.  I'm not sure what I did but perhaps someone could tell me why this sends 2 and how to fix it?

The other question I have is that on both notifications on the phone, the icon is zoomed in (or too big).  How do you make the push notification icon the correct size?

Here is my method

```
  private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, FriendGroupActivity.class);

    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);  




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
String appname = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
Notification notification;
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
    new Intent(context, myactivity.class), 0);

// To support 2.3 os, we use "Notification" class and 3.0+ os will use
// "NotificationCompat.Builder" class.
if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
notification = new Notification(icon, message, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, appname, message,
        contentIntent);
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

} else {
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
        context);
notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
        .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(0)
        .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
        .setContentText(message).build();

notificationManager.notify(0 , notification);
}
}
```

Hope this helps.This works for me.